# Relationship between two random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and $1_A:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ (the characteristic function of the subset $A$) and let $\sigma(X) := \{X^{-1}(B)| \text{ for } B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \}$ where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. I want to show that if $1_A$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, then there exists a $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable function $f$ such that $f \circ X = 1_A$.

I am a bit stumped  and I don't know how to prove its existence, except perhaps by constructing one, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $1_A$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, choose a Borel set $B$ so that $X^{-1}(B) = A$. Set $f(x) = 1_{B}$. Then $f$ is Borel measurable (since $B$ is a Borel set). If $\omega \in A$, then $X(\omega) \in B$ so $f\circ X(\omega) = 1$. Likewise, if $\omega \notin A$, then $\omega \notin B$ so $f\circ X(\omega) = 0$. Thus $f \circ X = 1_A$.

Comment: Why is $\ X(A)\ $ a Borel set?  Suppose $\ \Omega=\mathbb{R}\ $, $\ D\subseteq\mathbb{R}\ $ a non-Borel set, and
$$
X(x)=\cases{x&if $\ x\in D$\\
            0&if $\ x\notin D\ $.}
$$
Then
$$
    X^{-1}\left(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\right)=D\in\sigma(X)\ ,
$$
so $\ 1_D\ $ is $\ \sigma(X)$-measurable, but $\ X(D)=D\ $ is not Borel.  Your proof will work, however, if you simply replace $\ X(A)\ $ with some Borel $\ B\ $ with $\ A=X^{-1}(B)\ $.

Comment: @Ionza You are quite correct, I have updated the answer to reflect this.